# No overload matches this call - redux-saga error in simple saga example

Tags: redux, redux-saga

The following code gives the error: `No overload matches this call`

```
const deleteListItem = (id: string) =>
  axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/api/delete/${id}`);

function* deleteSaga(action: DeleteItemAction) {
  try {
    yield call(deleteListItem, action.id);
    yield put({
      type: DELETE_SUCCESS,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({
      type: DELETE_ERROR,
    });
  }
}
```

Full error:

> The last overload gave the following error.
>       Argument of type '(id: string) => Promise>' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ context: unknown; fn: (this:
>   unknown, ...args: any[]) => any; }'.
>         Type '(id: string) => Promise>' is missing the following properties from type '{ context: unknown; fn: (this:
>   unknown, ...args: any[]) => any; }': context, fn  TS2769

I have walked through all redux-saga issues but none of them helped me...

I could do `(action: any)` but this is not the solution for me... My interface for action:

```
interface DeleteItemAction {
  id?: string;
}
```

Comment: Did you omit TypeScript from your tags?

Comment: i could do `action: any` but this is not a solution for me...

Comment: Seems like the typing for `call` requires a generator and isn't typed to allow a function returning a `Promise`. Try `function* deleteListItem(id: string) { return axios.delete(\`http://localhost:4000/api/delete/${id}\`);}` instead.

Comment: not fixing as well :(

Comment: @heisenberg7584 Did you solve this?